# Making a console with a print comand

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that will print whatever is after "print:" in a console application (I don't know how else to explain it)

If you don't understand I think my code will help you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LiteConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string input = Console.In.ReadLine();
                char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
                if (input.Contains("print"))
                {
                    int Place = 0;
                    int colenPlace = 0;
                    foreach (char a in chars)
                    {
                        Place++;
                        if (chars[Place].Equals(":"))
                        {
                            colenPlace = Place;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.Write(input.Substring(colenPlace));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program and type "print:Hello World" it doesn't print "Hello World" like it should, it just goes to the next line.

Comment: I suspect that there is some better way to find position of character in string. Try search - i.e. Bing - [c# position char in string](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+position+char+in+string) or Yachoo https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=c%23+position+char+in+string if Google did not find anything.

Comment: Your a bit late but thanks anyways! I'll check out your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a quick glance I can see two bugs in your application:

**First**, if a `':'` character is never found, the code will generate an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  This is because you increment the index before you use it, so you're never comparing the first character of the input and will generate an exception after the last character.  Move `Place++;` to the end of the loop to solve this:

```
foreach (char a in chars)
{
    if (chars[Place].Equals(":"))
    {
        colenPlace = Place;
        break;
    }
    Place++;
}
```

**Second**, this will never be true:

```
chars[Place].Equals(":")
```

The value is a `char`, but you're comparing it to a `string`.  Compare it to a `char` instead:

```
chars[Place].Equals(':')
```

Or even just use a direct comparison (which should result in a compile-time error if you try to use a string by mistake):

```
chars(Place) == ':'
```

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit new to C#, sorry.

Comment: @ElliotLinn: No worries, we were all new once.  As a general word of advice, your *most valuable* tool as a developer is the debugger.  Use it to step through the code, line by line, as it executes.  You can examine runtime values, see how the logic behaves, etc.  This will really help you identify specific issues without having to picture the whole thing in your head at once.

Answer (score 0):

Could probably simplify it to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if input.StartsWith("print:")
            Console.WriteLine(input.Replace("print:", ""));
    }
}
```